# Common positional arguments in different subparsers

Tags: python, argparse, python-2.x

I am trying to make a parser using **argparse** than can parse the following commands:

```
python prog.py update <DOMAIN> <ENVIRONMENT>
python prog.py pull <DOMAIN> <ENVIRONMENT>
python prog.py release <DOMAIN> <ENVIRONMENT>
```

As you can see, both **update**, **pull** and **release** take the same arguments `<DOMAIN>` and `<ENVIRONMENT>`.

All three of them are subparsers of the main parser.

I wrote the following:

```
import argparse
# create the top-level parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG', add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('domain', type=str, help='domain help')
parser.add_argument('environment', type=str, help='environment help')

#subparsers
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help', parents=[parser])
parser_pull = subparsers.add_parser('pull', help='pull help')
parser_update = subparsers.add_parser('update', help='update help')
print parser_pull.parse_args(['pull', 'WEBAPPS', 'DEV'])
print parser.parse_args(['update', 'WEBAPPS', 'DEV'])
```

but it seems that **domain** and **environment** are expected BEFORE the subcommands **update**, **pull** and **release**, so it throws an error.

How can I make it required to accept those arguments after the subcommands, without duplicating code inside each subcommand ?

For the record, I use Python 2.7.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in argparse. Have you tried other modules, such as [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/), [optparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) (warning, is deprecated), or [docopt](http://docopt.org/)? I know there are others, and I have no idea if what you want is achievable in any of them, but if you're open to a 3rd-party library I'm sure you can find one that does this. (I personally enjoy using click, but like I said I don't know if it'll work for what you want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and duplicate the code.  A little cut and paste is not that much work.

Positional arguments have to be given in a certain order.  And `.add_subparsers` creates one of those positionals (one that expects values like 'pull','update'.  So the order of the subparse command, positionals defined for the main parser, and positionals for the subparsers matters.

There is a `parents` mechanism, which can save some typing.  But I hesitate to recommend it because it can cause problems (previous SO questions demonstrate this).  Simply biting the bullet and entering the positional arguments where they are expected is the surest approach.

Don't forget that you can create subparsers in a loop or with helper functions - saving one kind of typing for another.

For example, after creating the subparsers:

```
for p in parser_pull, parser_update:
    p.add_argument('domain', type=str, help='domain help')
    p.add_argument('environment', type=str, help='environment help')
```